# Understanding a proposition in Zeidler's book on functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

In my book on functional analysis by Zeidler he makes an important claim that

> Let $M \subset \mathbb{X}$, where $\mathbb{X}$ is a normed space then
>
> 1. $M$ is closed
> 2. $\forall u_n \in M, \forall n$, $u_n \to u$ as $n \to \infty$ where $u \in M$

He then goes to prove this using some lemma from convergence of cauchy sequence in Banach space.

To me this statement is very strong. If $\mathbb{X}$ is a normed space, i.e. a set ($\mathbb{X}, +, \times$) having a norm $|\cdot|$, then all of its subsets are closed.

I have three questions:

*1. Does it matter if $\mathbb{X}$ in consideration is of finite or infinite*

*2. Is there a trivial example that illustrates this property?*

*3. Is there a intuitive/pictorial way to think about this claim?*

Comment: It is not true that all subsets of a normed space are closed.

Comment: This is all nonsense. A book claims that every subset of a normed space is closed? I hope not - seems much more likely you're misunderstanding what's being said. (You should also note that the way (2) is _stated_ here is nonsense - "$\forall n u_n\to u$" makes no sense.)

Comment: What I think the book might be stating is that conditions 1. and 2. are _equivalent_, not that they are both true,

Comment: I am guessing that you are reading _Applied Functional Analysis_ by Zeidler, but there's a very slight chance you're reading one of the several volumes of his _Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications_. I recommend that you [edit] your question to state the title of the book you are reading, state the page number where you see this claim, and also quote the claim word-for-word (or symbol-for-symbol).

Comment: @Wojowu Ah, I bet that's it. (Of course we also have to assume a more coherent version of (2).)

Comment: Read the comments! No, he simply does _not_ make that claim. Tell us what he actually says. _NOT_ in your own words! Tell us _exactly_ what he says, word for word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I think the claim *actually* said (or at least, was meant to say):

> For $M \subset \Bbb X$ where $\Bbb X$ is a normed space, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $M$ is closed
> 2. For all sequences $(u_n)\subset M$, $u_n \to u$ as $n \to \infty$ implies that $u \in M$.

This is quite different from what you've stated.